# Check if folder exists and save two sheets in there VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, directory

I need VBA to check if folder with name "Secret_information" already exists. If folder already exists then I need to save PDF and Excel from Worksheet (1) to this folder with special name (see VBA below). If folder does not exists then create new folder in the same direction my opened Excel file is already located. I have made VBA but it doesn't work correctly. Now it doesn't create xls file only pdf. Also this code creates folder to Desktop, I need it to create folder inside folder my opened Excel file is located. How to make it work?

```
Sub CommercialPart()
   Dim NewPath As String
   NewPath = Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & "Secret_information"
   If Dir(NewPath, 63) = "" Then MkDir NewPath

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        Filename:=NewPath & "\Secret_information_" & [Pricelist!E2] & "_" & "SC" & [Technical!I11] & "_" & Date & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=No, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=False

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewPath & "\Secret_information_" & [Pricelist!E2] & "_" & "DD" & [Material!J8] & "_" & Date
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are missing `\` in `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "" & "Secret_information"` so it should be `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Secret_information"`
2. you are missing extension at the end of this line , also format the date, its more readable that way 
   `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewPath & "\Secret_information_" &
   [Pricelist!E2] & "_" & "DD" & [Material!J8] & "_" & Date` it should be `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewPath & "\Secret_information_" & [Pricelist!E2] & "_" & "DD" & [Material!J8] & "_" & Format(Date,"ddmmmyy" )& ".xls",xlExcel8`

Add the file format for xls as `xlExcel8`

Comment: Thank you! Works good. The only problem is that this command:                       `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).SaveAs NewPath & "\Secret_information_" & [Pricelist!E2] & "_" & "SC" & [Technical!I11] & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyy") & ".xls", xlExcel8`                                      creates new excel document with all the sheets from original. I need it to copy only the sheet number one. Also I want it to delete all the functions from the sheet while creating.

Comment: these questions where not the part of original post. must read this : http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/ optional reading : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Actually I have asked "I need to save PDF and Excel from Worksheet (1) to this folder with special name". You can notice that there is mentioned that I need xls to be created from Worksheet number one, not the whole workbook. Anyways thank you for your help but there is no need to send links for reading if you haven't read the question...

Comment: need to save PDF and Excel from Worksheet (1), code  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy`
        `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs NewPath...` whats the issue?? it will create a new workbook  with first sheet. Now in the comment you came up with this agile piece of code... `ThisWorkbook.Sheets‌​(1).SaveAs NewPath &...` out of no where.... hence the link.

Comment: don't focus on being condescending, try to be humble and direct.